# path issue to access file in assets folder in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native project and in the assets folder there is a model.glb file that needs to be accessed by Model.js which is not in the assets folder. I thought

import newModel as ./assets/model.glb

would work but I get an error that it can't be found

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the import line above, import newModel as NEW from '.assets/model.glb'

Comment: Sorry just to be clear you're saying the line should be "import newModel as NEW from './assets/model.glb"?

Comment: Yes, and also check the path that is correct accessed or not

Comment: But when I do this vscode underlines it red as an error. Just to be clear, this is react native - I’m not using typescript or anything like that

Comment: sorry, ur question is not explained in detail